# Is there a, way to find the end point API protected by cloudflair?

Tags: api, cloudflare, endpoint

I am trying to perform  resonance for a web application been attempting to try and retrieve the end point API hidden behind cloudflair I tried using [CloudFail](https://github.com/m0rtem/CloudFail) did retrieve a couple of subdomains still protected by cloudflair. So it was of no use. Is there any other way to retrieve the end point behind cloudflair? Or tool that I can use to bypass cloudflair to retrieve the End point API?

I even tried using postman but could not get to the end point API

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to get the Origin of an API proxied by CF. You're wasting your time.